# How to verify Everyone has permissions to a shared folder VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a way to verify that a shared folder is shared for EveryBody

The below code works by specifying a user.

```
        Dim FolderPath As String = "C:\test"
        Dim UserAccount As String = "DESKTOP-B47UK7U\Everyone"
        Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)
        Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
        FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow))
        FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl)
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean? you did not specified any user in that code

Comment: I what it for all users.  "Everyone" as in the picture.  

When sharing a folder manually right-clicking the folder then Properties.  Sharing tab then click the button Share.  Select everyone from the drop-down list and you can set the Permission Level for Everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by getting the `SecurityIdentifier` for the `Everyone` user, which is actually named the `WorldSid`.  You can obtain it like this:

```
Dim EveryoneIdentifier As SecurityIdentifier = New SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, Nothing)
```

In your code this could be implemented as such:

```
Dim FolderPath As String = "C:\test"
Dim EveryoneIdentifier As SecurityIdentifier = New SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, Nothing)
Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)
Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(EveryoneIdentifier, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow))
FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl)
```

The list of accounts available in the WellKnownSidType enumeration are detailed in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype?view=net-5.0).  In the case of `WorldSid`:

> Indicates a SID that matches everyone.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for.